# A question about the covariance matrix of a bivariate normal distribution

Tags: multivariate-analysis, feature-selection, covariance-matrix

I am reading the paper [Feature Screening via Distance Correlation Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.4701.pdf) and I have some difficulties understanding **Example 3** on **page 15**:

Let $\mathbf{x}=(X_1,...,X_p)^T$ from normal distribution with zero mean and covariance matrix
$\Sigma=(\sigma_{ij})_{p\times p}$. We fix the sample size to $n=200$ and vary the dimension $p=2000$ to $p=5000$ (page 10) .

**Example 3.**
Our aim is to generate $\mathbf{y}=(Y_1,Y_2)$ from bivariate normal distribution with mean zero and covariance matrix $\Sigma_{\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x}}=(\sigma_{x,ij})_{2\times 2}$ with $\sigma_{x,11}=\sigma_{x,22}=1$ and $\sigma_{x,12}=\sigma_{x,21}=\sin(b_1^T\mathbf{x})$
where $b_1=(0.8,0.6,0,...,0)^T$ (case 3.a of the paper). The idea is to make $X_1$ and $X_2$ affect $\mathbf{y}$.

---

My question is how it is possible for $b_1^T\mathbf{x}$ to be a real number. The matrix $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p} $ has $n$ rows and $p$ columns so I am not positive that the multiplication of a $n\times p$ matrix with any matrix or vector can result to a real number.

I even have trouble understanding the dimensions of $b_1$ in the first place. Maybe $b_1\in \mathbb{R}^{1\times p}$ and $\sigma_{x,12}$ equals $\mathbf{x}b_1^T$ and not $b_1^T\mathbf{x}$.
But even in this case the multiplication of $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p} $ with $b_1^T\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times 1}$ would result to a $n\times 1$ vector and not a real number.

Comment: This is a confusion with notations: $\mathbf x$ represents one realisation of the $n$-sample and is thus a vector of $\mathbb R^p$, which makes $b_1^\text{T}\mathbf x$ a scalar.

Comment: @Xi'an Oh I didn't know $\mathbf{x}$ represented one realization of the sample. Thanks for the answer! So if $x \in \mathbb{R}^p$ then I use this realization to generate a $y \in \mathbb{R}^2$, am I right? And if I want to generate $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 2}$ then I use every realization of the $n$-sample with the same way, am I correct?